# Can't access current value in select option input

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

In my meteor application, I need to get the current value of a select option field.

My markup:

```
<select multiple id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

In the template events I declare the [event map](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) as follow:

```
Template.objectsList.events({

  // #category represents my select option input
  "change #category": function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.options);
  },

  // ...
});
```

in the console this would always print:

```
[option, option, option, option, selectedIndex: 0, namedItem: function, add: function, remove: function, item: function]
    0: option
    1: option
    2: option
    3: option
    length: 4
    selectedIndex: 0
    __proto__: HTMLOptionsCollection
```

No matter, which option I select in the browser window, the selectedIndex attribute would always equal 0. How can I get the actual selectedIndex, so I can get the value of the currently selected item?

**EDIT 1**

I'm using [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) as UI framework and I initiate my select option fields as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

**EDIT 2**

It has to do with how the select option element is rendered with materialize, there is [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852418/getting-the-value-off-a-select-option-box-in-javascript-i-am-using-materialize) and [discussion on github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3667) about this topic.

Thing is, **materialize** would **manipulate** the **DOM** and **render** a ul List instead of the initial `select option` element:

```
  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-76ad55d8-1376-b852-a496-ef2926e59632" value="Please select">
  <ul id="select-options-76ad55d8-1376-b852-a496-ef2926e59632" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 420px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
    <li class="disabled"><span>Please select</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Option 1</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Option 2</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Option 3</span></li>
  </ul>
```

So the solution would be to either

- A get the selected value from the rendered ul li list (ugly)
- execute the JS init at the time after the onchange event would already have gathered the current values (if possible)

Comment: can you check with event.target.value

Comment: @saikumar it fires but the output is empty

Comment: it must have to do with materialize. when I use a native select option field, it works..

Comment: ok..I don't have any knowledge on http://materializecss.com/

Answer (score 0):

Due materialize manipulating the DOM and implementing the select view using an unordered list (`ul`), the current value can be retrieved using jquery:

```
$("#category").val(); // #category represents the original select option we want to read
```

This will get an array of the currently selected values. If only one value should be selected, the `multiple` attribute should be removed from the `<select>` tag:

```
<!-- only 1 attribute selectable -->
<select id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<!-- multiple attributes selectable -->
<select multiple id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

event map:

```
Template.objectsList.events({
  "change #category": function (event) {
    var selectedValue = $("#category").val();
    // do something with selectedValue
  },
// ...
```

Comment: Notice: Do not use ids to adress elements inside a template as ids should be unique on a document. Also, never use jQuery unscoped inside a meteor-template. You can scope jQuery to a template with template.$(...). You receive the template-instance-variable as second parameter in your event-handler or with Template.instance()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="category>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

```
"change #category": function(e, t) {
 var changedValue = $(e.currentTarget).val();
}
```